# How to fix Javascript obfuscation virus from website

Tags: javascript, web, obfuscation, antivirus, malware

I'm having a problem with the website I'm helping manage. Visitors are getting a JavaScript Obfuscation warning from our site. We haven't purposely obfuscated any of our code, which only leaves a malicious attack as the probable cause.  It doesn't look like our antivirus is going to fix the problem. I'm not finding a whole lot of useful information on this issue online. What should I do to address this? Is there some utility that would work for a Linux server that may help us find the source of the problem, and remove the threat?

Comment: Are any of your pages including external/3rd party scripts?

Comment: What in the world is a "JavaScript Obfuscation" warning? *edit* ah OK thanks @Brad

Comment: AVG warns of JavaScript obfuscation, 'eh?  That seems incredibly useless and arbitrary.

Comment: Ridiculous:  http://www.avgthreatlabs.com/webthreats/info/javascript-obfuscation/

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/418121/what-is-javascript-obfuscation-and-why-is-it-a-threat

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to compare what is on your server now to what you put there originally.  That should tell you whether it's in the same state you originally deployed.

If it is not in the same state, put it back in that state (e.g. by getting source from version control) and conduct a full security audit.

If indeed the code is what you originally put there, it is possible that a third-party JavaScript library that you are using (or your own libraries if you minify your code using certain techniques) is triggering a false positive with an anti-virus product.  If that is the case, figure out which anti-virus soultion(s) trigger a warning and submit a false-positive report to that vendor.  Every major anti-virus vendor has a means to submit false positive reports online.  They are typically acted on within a few days.